# how check box check and unchecked automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, checkbox, textfield

We have one `table` in which we have three `td` like this:

**HTML:**

```
<table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" name="favcolor" id="checkbox" value="red"></td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td><input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" ></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

We need a function that checks the check-box as soon as the text field receives any input. If the text field is cleared of all input (becomes empty) the check-box should become unchecked again.

Can someone lead me into the right direction?

Comment: its easy, just have an event for the textfield onchange or keyup, check the value in the textfield and if it matches the value in the option tag, set the attr('checked', true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `input` event

```js
$(function() {
  var chk = $('#checkbox');
  $('#textfield').on('input', function() { //fire as user types/drag-drop/copy-paste
    //replace all white-space and get the actual text length
    //if lenght is greater than 0, mark it else un-mark
    chk.prop('checked', this.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="favcolor" id="checkbox" value="red">
    </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>
      <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
$('#textfield').on('change',function(){
  $("#checkbox").prop('checked',$(this).val().length);
});
```

OR Instead of using `change` event you can also use `keyup`.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aez7pt2y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a change event handler like

```js
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function($) {
  //a change event handler for the input field
  $('#textfield').change(function() {
    //based on whether the input has a value set the checked state
    $('#checkbox').prop('checked', this.value.length > 0)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="favcolor" id="checkbox" value="red" />
    </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>
      <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```